# Error (#230) Permissions disallow message to user api Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

i have some problem with the open graph api when i try to send a message through the api.

Here is my code :

```
try {
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
        $response = $fb->post(
            '/' . $conversation_id . '/messages',
            array(
                'message' => $this->source['message'],
            ),
            $token_page
        );

        $this->loadModel("PageAccount");
        $currentPage = $this->PageAccount->findById($this->source['page_id']);

        $token = $this->source['token'];
        $data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/" . $this->source['conversation_id'] . "?access_token=$token&fields=messages.limit(200){message,created_time,to,from}");
        $data = json_decode($data, 1);

        $view = new View($this, false);
        $element = $view->element("admin/conversations/all-conversation", array("conversation" => $data));

        return $this->getSuccessResult(array("conversation" => $element));

    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        return $this->getErrorResult("Une erreur est survenue");
    }
```

The error that Facebook send me : 
(#230) Permissions disallow message to user

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: are you replying to a user message? and the conversation is from page to user?

Comment: if that does not help, read this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206829&type=1

Comment: Yes this is an answer to a message, this is for a page. I developed a tool, you can answer to users who contact the page.

Comment: did you try with different users too?

Comment: Yes i tried with 2 different users :)

Comment: Any update ? Still not found the solution :(